# onClick :call a function from componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="sendSms">
            <h1  className="distance">signup</h1>
            <input className="text-right" onClick={ostype} id="input1" name="mobileNumber" pattern="[0-9]+" type="text" placeholder="mobile" required />
            <input name="osVersion" id="input2" type="hidden" value="" />
            <input name="osType" id="input3" type="hidden" value="" />
            <input name="deviceID" id="input4" type="hidden" value="Come on" />

            <button className="distance" type="submit" onClick={sendData}>submit</button>
        </form>
```

I want to `sendData` function POST the inputs to api

the function:

```
  function sendData() {
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'some api i have',
        data: sendSms,
    })

    .then(res => this.setState({ recipes: res.data }));

}

var sendSms = 
{
    'mobileNumber' : document.getElementById("input1"),
    'osVersion' : document.getElementById("input2"),
    'osType' : document.getElementById("input3"),
    'deviceID' : document.getElementById("input4"),
}
```

I tried to put axios in `componentDidMount()` but that way i cant call the `sendData` functuion with onClick.
and when i put the function in my code, i get `NS_BINDING_ABORTED`

Comment: If you need the data from the form to make the API call, why do you want to also make the call in componentDIdMount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Using Hooks
export default function SMSView() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        mobileNumber: '',
        osVersion: '',
        osType: '',
        deviceID: ''
    })

    const handleChange = ({target: {value, name}}) => {
        setState({...state, [name]: value})
    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        // axios here
    }

    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="mobileNumber" value={state.mobileNumber} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input name="osVersion" value={state.osVersion} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input name="osType" value={state.osType} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input name="deviceID" value={state.deviceID} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
}

// Using Class Component
export default class SMSView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mobileNumber: '',
            osVersion: '',
            osType: '',
            deviceID: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange = ({target: {value, name}}) => {
        this.setState({...this.state, [name]: value})
    }

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        // axios here
    }

    render() {
        const {mobileNumber, osVersion, osType, deviceID} = this.state
        return <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input name="mobileNumber" value={mobileNumber} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input name="osVersion" value={osVersion} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input name="osType" value={osType} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input name="deviceID" value={deviceID} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    }
}
```

or use libraries like [React Hook Form][1]

```
[1]: https://react-hook-form.com/
```

Comment: i dont know much about hooks got this error: 
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
can u pls say where to paste the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed two worlds in your code: In the below code(that you have written) to get the Values from the inputs, The approach is `Imperative` but still it is wrong, You are not assigning any value but directly assigning DOM elements to your `sendSms` object.

```
var sendSms = 
{
    'mobileNumber' : document.getElementById("input1"),
    'osVersion' : document.getElementById("input2"),
    'osType' : document.getElementById("input3"),
    'deviceID' : document.getElementById("input4"),
}
```

You should use a **Controlled Component Approach** instead to get values of your inputs.

Secondly, There should not be any error at all if you use onClick the way you have, You do not need to use `ComponentDidMount` at all.

You simply should check two things,before sending your data via Post Axios request.

1. Whether I have the available data from inputs.
2. Whether server is allowing for Post call.

So, you need to do some homework dear Friend, Let me share some resources.

From Official React Docs [Controlled Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Making post call (on Form submit exactly what you require)  https://reactgo.com/react-post-request-axios/

**Please Note:** Though Class based approach will work but from React 16.8, React is officially using React Hooks, do have a look into that as well https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score -1):

For onClick event you must to do like this :

```
onClick={() => sendData()}
```

After I advise you to use Function components instead of Class components and use Hook instead directly use state and lifecycle fonction.